# How to automate a BigQuery SQL pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I created a data pipeline using BigQuery SQL.
It starts by importing a CSV file from Cloud Storage, then it is doing different analysis including Predictive modeling using BigQueryML 
Geography calculation using Geography functions, and
KPIs computation using Analytic functions.

I am able to successfully run the different queries manually, and now i would like to automate the data pipeline.

My first choice was DataFlow SQL but it turns out that Dataflow SQL query syntax does not support geography functions.

DataFlow python is less of an option since the complete analysis is done in SQL and i would like to keep it this way.

My question is what are the other GCP options available to automate the data pipeline.

Comment: How complex do you need? Could you simply use scheduled queries? If you need more complexity I would use python, even if all your steps are functional SQL, you can just use python to orchestrate them.

Comment: It is quite complex. and there are about 8 queries that i need to orchestrate.

Comment: do you suggest to use the Dataflow in Python ?

Comment: Personally I find Dataflow complex and overly-heavy for my similar requirements of running several SQL queries. A nice tool for automating SQL (and other) jobs is CRMint, maybe this is a good middle ground for you? https://github.com/google/crmint

Comment: Intresting, i will give it a try. thank you Ben.

Comment: https://cloud.getdbt.com/ This is a good solution we currently use. You basically orchestrate data pipelines in almost pure SQL.

Comment: Very nice, thank you Francesco, i will check it out.

Comment: You can also give cloud composer a shot https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-transfer-bigquery-tables-between-locations-with-cloud-composer

Comment: Check out Magnus - Workflow Automator which is part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com) Suite - supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc.. Also available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio). Disclosure: I am creator of those tools and leader on Potens team

Comment: Thank you Mikhail i will surely try it out.

Comment: If your queries work like a pipeline, in other words, if you need a query to be completed to run another query, I would suggest that you take a look in Cloud Composer

Comment: yes, there are dependencies, i will look into it, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, if you need to orchestrate your queries you can use `Cloud Composer`, a fully managed `Airflow` cluster.

I created the code below to show you more or less how could you orchestrate your queries  using this tool. Please notice that this is a basic code and can be improved in terms of coding standards.
The code basically orchestrate 3 queries:

1. The first one reads from a public table and write to another table in your project
2. The second one reads the table created in your first query and select the 10000 newest rows based in a date column. After that, it saves the result to a table in your project.
3. The third one reads the table created in the step 2 and calculate some aggregations. After that, it saves the results to another table in your project.

   ```
   import datetime
   from airflow import models
   from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator

   """The condiguration presented below will run your DAG every five minutes as specified in the 
   schedule_interval property starting from the datetime specified in the start_date property"""

   default_dag_args = {
       'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 22, 15, 40), 
       'email_on_failure': False,
       'email_on_retry': False,
       'retries': 1,
       'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
       'project_id': "<your_project_id>",
   }

   with models.DAG(
           'composer_airflow_bigquery_orchestration',
           schedule_interval = "*/5 * * * *",
           default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

       run_first_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
           sql = "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.catalonian_mobile_coverage.mobile_data_2015_2017`",
           destination_dataset_table = "<your_project>.<your_dataset>.orchestration_1",
           task_id = 'xxxxxxxx',
           write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
           #create_disposition = "",
           allow_large_results = True,
           use_legacy_sql = False
       )

       run_second_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
           sql = "SELECT * FROM `<your_project>.orchestration_1` ORDER BY date LIMIT 10000 ",
           destination_dataset_table = "<your_project>.<your_dataset>.orchestration_2",
           task_id = 'yyyyyyyy',
           write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
           #create_disposition = "",
           allow_large_results = True,
           use_legacy_sql = False
       )

       run_third_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
           sql = "SELECT round(lat) r_lat, round(long) r_long, count(1) total FROM`<your_project>.orchestration_2` GROUP BY r_lat,r_long",
           destination_dataset_table = "<your_project>.<your_dataset>.orchestration_3",
           task_id = 'zzzzzzzz',
           write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
           #create_disposition = "",
           allow_large_results = True,
           use_legacy_sql = False
       )


      # Define DAG dependencies.
       run_first_query >> run_second_query >> run_third_query
   ```

**Going step by step:**

- First, its imported some Airflow libraries like models and bigquery_operator

  ```
  from airflow import models
  from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator
  ```
- Then its defined a dict named `default_dag_args` that will be used further when you create your DAG.

  ```
  default_dag_args = {
      'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 22, 15, 40), 
      'email_on_failure': False,
      'email_on_retry': False,
      'retries': 1,
      'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
      'project_id': "<your_project_id>",
  }
  ```
- When you create your DAG, you pass the `default_dag_args` dict as the default argument and add the `schedule interval` argument that will define when your DAG should be run. You can use this argument with some preset expressions or using CRON expressions as you can see [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html)

  ```
  with models.DAG(
          'composer_airflow_bigquery_orchestration',
          schedule_interval = "*/5 * * * *",
          default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
  ```
- After that, you can create your operator's instances. In this case we are using only the [BigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html)

  ```
      run_first_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
          sql = "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.catalonian_mobile_coverage.mobile_data_2015_2017`",
          destination_dataset_table = "<your_project>.<your_dataset>.orchestration_1",
          task_id = 'xxxxxxxx',
          write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
          #create_disposition = "",
          allow_large_results = True,
          use_legacy_sql = False
      )

      run_second_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
          sql = "SELECT * FROM `<your_project>.orchestration_1` ORDER BY date LIMIT 10000 ",
          destination_dataset_table = "<your_project>.<your_dataset>.orchestration_2",
          task_id = 'yyyyyyyy',
          write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
          #create_disposition = "",
          allow_large_results = True,
          use_legacy_sql = False
      )

      run_third_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
          sql = "SELECT round(lat) r_lat, round(long) r_long, count(1) total FROM`<your_project>.orchestration_2` GROUP BY r_lat,r_long",
          destination_dataset_table = "<your_project>.<your_dataset>.orchestration_3",
          task_id = 'zzzzzzzz',
          write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
          #create_disposition = "",
          allow_large_results = True,
          use_legacy_sql = False
      )
  ```
- As a last step, we can define the dependencies for the DAG. This piece of code means that the run_second_query operation depends on the conclusion of the run_first_query and so it goes.

  ```
      run_first_query >> run_second_query >> run_third_query
  ```

Finally, I would like to add this [article](https://medium.com/intage-analytics/airflow-trick-to-find-the-exact-start-date-via-cron-expression-23b5351007b) that discuss how to set the start_date and schedule_interval correctly when using CRON expressions.

Comment: Thank you, your example was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery has an inbuilt scheduling mechanism that's in beta features currently.

To automate a BQ native SQL pipeline, you can use this utility. 
Using CLI:

```
$ bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--destination_table=mydataset.mytable \
--display_name='My Scheduled Query' \
--replace=true \
'SELECT
1
FROM
mydataset.test'
```