# How to query a BigQuery table in one GCP project and one location and write results to a table in another project and another location with Airflow?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I need to query a BigQuery table in one GCP project (say #1) and one location (EU) and write results to a table in another project (say #2) and another location (US) with Airflow.

Composer/Airflow instance itself runs in project #2 and location US.

Airflow is using GCP connection configured with a service account from project #2 which also has most of the rights in project #1.

I realise that this might involve multiple extra steps such as storing data temporarily in GCS, so this is fine as long as the end result is achieved.

How should I approach this problem? I saw quite a few articles but none does suggest a strategy for dealing with this situation which I suppose is fairly common.

Comment: As you said, a way to do this, and a common way, is to get the data from BQ then push it to GCS, and then use the GCStoBQ Operator to load on it. In airflow, you can do also this by pushing the data to XCOM but this could carry out issues like consistency. So better use GCS  to keep the track.

Comment: Does this answer your question [stackoverflow.com/questions/61345381](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345381/how-to-automate-a-bigquery-sql-pipeline/61370710#61370710)?

Comment: Hi @MaximVolgin, Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?